# Trying to pass Variable in java from one class/Jframe to another but program complies and nothing happens?

Tags: java

Right so I have my ItemsPage Jframe Class and I'm trying to pass my TotalPrice variable to my CashPay so I can calculate the change. CashPrice runs and works but when I try run ItemsPage it does nothing I don't even get errors. I tried to remove that small section of trying to pass the variable to CashPay and it worked perfectly so I 100% know that's the problem. This section "public ItemsPage() {
        Pounds = "£";
        //super();

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    CashPay sendTotalPrice = new CashPay();
    //System.out.println("Enter your amount");
    TotalPrice = sc.nextDouble();
    sendTotalPrice.printTotalPrice(TotalPrice);
    "
```

Here is complete code for both classes, I'm using GUI builder.

```js
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Checkbox;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


/**
* This code was edited or generated using CloudGarden's Jigloo
* SWT/Swing GUI Builder, which is free for non-commercial
* use. If Jigloo is being used commercially (ie, by a corporation,
* company or business for any purpose whatever) then you
* should purchase a license for each developer using Jigloo.
* Please visit www.cloudgarden.com for details.
* Use of Jigloo implies acceptance of these licensing terms.
* A COMMERCIAL LICENSE HAS NOT BEEN PURCHASED FOR
* THIS MACHINE, SO JIGLOO OR THIS CODE CANNOT BE USED
* LEGALLY FOR ANY CORPORATE OR COMMERCIAL PURPOSE.
*/
public class ItemsPage extends javax.swing.JFrame {
 private JLabel Fruitslbl;
 private JLabel Snackslbl;
 private JCheckBox Appleschk;
 private JCheckBox Strawberrychk;
 private JButton Continuebtn;
 private static JButton Additemsbtn;
 private JCheckBox Smoothiechk;
 private JCheckBox Juicechk;
 private JCheckBox Sodachk;
 private JCheckBox Lambchk;
 private JCheckBox Chickenchk;
 private JCheckBox Chocolatechk;
 private JCheckBox Crispschk;
 private JCheckBox Orangeschk;
 private JLabel Drinkslbl;
 private JLabel Meatlbl;
 public double TotalPrice;
 private String Pounds;
 
 

 /**
 * Auto-generated main method to display this JFrame
 */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    ItemsPage inst = new ItemsPage();
    inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    inst.setVisible(true);
    //Additemsbtn.addActionListener(
     //        new ActionListener()
   }
  });
 }
 
 public ItemsPage() {
  Pounds = "£";
  //super();
  
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  CashPay sendTotalPrice = new CashPay();
  //System.out.println("Enter your amount");
  TotalPrice = sc.nextDouble();
  sendTotalPrice.printTotalPrice(TotalPrice);
  
 }
 
 private void initGUI() {
  try {
   GridBagLayout thisLayout = new GridBagLayout();
   setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
   thisLayout.rowWeights = new double[] {0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1};
   thisLayout.rowHeights = new int[] {7, 7, 7, 7};
   thisLayout.columnWeights = new double[] {0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1};
   thisLayout.columnWidths = new int[] {7, 7, 7, 7};
   getContentPane().setLayout(thisLayout);
   this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("")).getImage());

   Fruitslbl = new JLabel();
   getContentPane().add(Fruitslbl, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
   Fruitslbl.setText("Fruits");

   Snackslbl = new JLabel();
   getContentPane().add(Snackslbl, new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
   Snackslbl.setText("Snacks");

   Meatlbl = new JLabel();
   getContentPane().add(Meatlbl, new GridBagConstraints(2, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
   Meatlbl.setText("Meat");

   Drinkslbl = new JLabel();
   getContentPane().add(Drinkslbl, new GridBagConstraints(3, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
   Drinkslbl.setText("Drinks");

   Appleschk = new JCheckBox();
   getContentPane().add(Appleschk, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
   Appleschk.setText("Apples");

   Orangeschk = new JCheckBox();
   getContentPane().add(Orangeschk, new GridBagConstraints(0, 2, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
   Orangeschk.setText("Oranges");

   Strawberrychk = new JCheckBox();
   getContentPane().add(Strawberrychk, new GridBagConstraints(0, 3, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
   Strawberrychk.setText("Strawberry");
   

   Crispschk = new JCheckBox();
   getContentPane().add(Crispschk, new GridBagConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
   Crispschk.setText("Crisps");
   
   

   Chocolatechk = new JCheckBox();
   getContentPane().add(Chocolatechk, new GridBagConstraints(1, 2, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
   Chocolatechk.setText("Chocolate");

   Chickenchk = new JCheckBox();
   getContentPane().add(Chickenchk, new GridBagConstraints(2, 1, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
   Chickenchk.setText("Chicken");

   Lambchk = new JCheckBox();
   getContentPane().add(Lambchk, new GridBagConstraints(2, 2, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
   Lambchk.setText("Lamb");

   Sodachk = new JCheckBox();
   getContentPane().add(Sodachk, new GridBagConstraints(3, 1, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
   Sodachk.setText("Soda");

   Juicechk = new JCheckBox();
   getContentPane().add(Juicechk, new GridBagConstraints(3, 2, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
   Juicechk.setText("Juice");

   Smoothiechk = new JCheckBox();
   getContentPane().add(Smoothiechk, new GridBagConstraints(3, 3, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
   Smoothiechk.setText("Smoothie");

   Additemsbtn = new JButton();
   getContentPane().add(Additemsbtn, new GridBagConstraints(1, 3, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
   Additemsbtn.setText("Add Items");
   Additemsbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
     //System.out.println("Additemsbtn.actionPerformed, event="+evt+TotalPrice);
     //TODO add your code for Additemsbtn.actionPerformed
     checkwhatIsSelected();
    }
   });

   Continuebtn = new JButton();
   getContentPane().add(Continuebtn, new GridBagConstraints(2, 3, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
   Continuebtn.setText("Complete Checkout");
   Continuebtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
     //System.out.println("Continuebtn.actionPerformed, event="+evt);
     //TODO add your code for Continuebtn.actionPerformed
     new CashPay().setVisible(true); // Main Form to show after the Login Form..
     CashPay CashPay = new CashPay();
     CashPay.printTotalPrice(TotalPrice);
    }
   });

   pack();
   this.setSize(841, 593);
  } catch (Exception e) {
      //add your error handling code here
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
 }

    
 // private void handleJCheckbox(double Strawberrychk) {
    
   

  // if (Strawberrychk. == true)
  //  TotalPrice += 1.99;
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  //return false;}
 
  public void checkwhatIsSelected() 
  {
   if(Strawberrychk.isSelected())
   {
    //is checked 
    TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
    System.out.println("   #################################################");
    System.out.println("       Your Total Price is: " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
    
    System.out.println("Thank you for shopping with Jstore, please come again!");
    System.out.println("   #################################################");
       }
   
   if(Appleschk.isSelected())
   {
    //is checked 
    TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 0.87;
    System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
    
   if(Orangeschk.isSelected())
    {
     //is checked 
    TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
    System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
   if(Crispschk.isSelected())
   {
    //is checked 
    TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
    System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
   }
   if(Lambchk.isSelected())
   {
    //is checked 
    TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
    System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
   }
   if(Chickenchk.isSelected())
   {
    //is checked 
    TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
    System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
   }
   if(Juicechk.isSelected())
   {
    //is checked 
    TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
    System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
   }
   
   }
   if(Smoothiechk.isSelected())
   {
    //is checked 
    TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
    System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
   }
   if(Sodachk.isSelected())
   {
    //is checked 
    TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
    System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
   }
   System.out.println("   #################################################");
   System.out.println("       Your Total Price is: " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
   
   System.out.println("Thank you for shopping with Jstore, please come again!");
   System.out.println("   #################################################");
   
  /* else 
    TotalPrice = TotalPrice +  0.00;*/
  }
 /* }
 private void Strawberrychk() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }*/

 /*private void handleCheckbox1(Checkbox Appleschk) {
    
      if (Appleschk.getState()) TotalPrice += 0.99;
      else TotalPrice += 0.00;
    
    }
  private void handleCheckbox2(Checkbox Orangeschk) {
    
      if (Orangeschk.getState()) TotalPrice += 1.99;
      else TotalPrice += 0.00;
    
    }
  private void handleCheckbox3(Checkbox Crispschk) {
    
      if (Crispschk.getState()) TotalPrice += 0.89;
      else TotalPrice += 0.00;
    
    }
  private void handleCheckbox4(Checkbox Chocolateschk) {
    
      if (Chocolateschk.getState()) TotalPrice += 0.99;
      else TotalPrice += 0.00;
    
    }*/
 
  

}
}
```

Here is the CashPay Class Jframe

```js
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


/**
* This code was edited or generated using CloudGarden's Jigloo
* SWT/Swing GUI Builder, which is free for non-commercial
* use. If Jigloo is being used commercially (ie, by a corporation,
* company or business for any purpose whatever) then you
* should purchase a license for each developer using Jigloo.
* Please visit www.cloudgarden.com for details.
* Use of Jigloo implies acceptance of these licensing terms.
* A COMMERCIAL LICENSE HAS NOT BEEN PURCHASED FOR
* THIS MACHINE, SO JIGLOO OR THIS CODE CANNOT BE USED
* LEGALLY FOR ANY CORPORATE OR COMMERCIAL PURPOSE.
*/
public class CashPay extends javax.swing.JFrame {

 private JLabel cashamountlbl;
 private JButton Calculatebtn;
 private JLabel CashChangelbl;
 private JTextField CashAmounttxt;
 private double ChangeLeft;
 
 

 /**
 * Auto-generated main method to display this JFrame
 */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    CashPay inst = new CashPay();
    inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    inst.setVisible(true);
    
   }
   
  });
  ItemsPage callClass = new ItemsPage();
  callClass.checkwhatIsSelected();
 }
 //Converts input from textfield into double variable.
 public CashPay() {
  super();
  
  initGUI();
 //Receives variable from another class "ItemsPage" 
 }
 public void printTotalPrice(double TotalPrice){
  double CashInsert = Double.parseDouble(CashAmounttxt.getText());
  ChangeLeft = CashInsert - TotalPrice;
  System.out.println (ChangeLeft);
 
 }
 private void initGUI() {
  try {
   setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
   getContentPane().setLayout(null);

   cashamountlbl = new JLabel();
   getContentPane().add(cashamountlbl);
   cashamountlbl.setText("Enter Cash Amount");
   cashamountlbl.setBounds(41, 65, 105, 34);
   cashamountlbl.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(128,0,255));

   CashAmounttxt = new JTextField();
   getContentPane().add(CashAmounttxt);
   CashAmounttxt.setBounds(215, 71, 87, 23);

   CashChangelbl = new JLabel();
   getContentPane().add(CashChangelbl);
   CashChangelbl.setBounds(190, 117, 158, 109);
   CashChangelbl.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255,128,64));

   Calculatebtn = new JButton();
   getContentPane().add(Calculatebtn);
   Calculatebtn.setText("Calculate Total");
   Calculatebtn.setBounds(46, 203, 93, 23);
   Calculatebtn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
   });

   pack();
   this.setSize(415, 319);
  } catch (Exception e) {
      //add your error handling code here
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
  
/*private void CashCal(){
 if (CashInsert => RecievedTotalPrice)}
}*/
```

Comment: Please be kind enough to explain and maybe show me how to do it I'm really new to java so some things I'm doing I might not know what they're called so when you say the technique/method name I might not know what youre talking about.

Comment: When you run itemPage, you are suppose to enter an amount in the console window, are you doing that.  You commented out the System.out.printLine(""Enter your amount"), so you are not seeming this in the console window to continue

Comment: No I don't want it to be able to type in the console, "enter your name" was just for something else I was experimenting with. what my program is able to do is you scan your products, then it tells you your total, then you get the option to either pay by card or pay by cash so  once you go in to cashpay you enter your cash amount in the jtextfield which then is "CashInsert - TotalPrice" = display answer in Label.

Comment: sorry, but your question is not clear.  You stated that " I try run ItemsPage it does nothing" but ItemsPage is asking for console input, sc.nextDouble().  You may want to just put only the code that does not work.

Comment: Scroll up at the top I already stated the section that doesn't work its 4 lines of code, I explain that I want a variable to be passed to CashPay so what eve is stored in TotalPrice I want that answer moved to CashPay that's what I'm trying to do and it that particular part of the code is making the program do nothing not even show errors so if I'm doing it wrong show me what I need to do instead please.

Comment: See my answer below, let me know if you have any questions.  I tested it and it works

Answer (score 0):

Here are the changes I made to your code to make it work, it will help you but I would recommend into looking at some basic java tutorials so that the changes I made make some sense,

Several issues, first the first 4 lines of code refer to a console input, second, initGUI is not being called in main of ItemsPage() to show the main panel.

First change your ItemsPage() constructor, just call initGUI()

```
 public ItemsPage() 
  {
        Pounds = "£";
        initGUI();

    }
```

To call CashPay and use it to calculate the difference, all you need to do is construct it and pass the total price to it once the use click on Complete Checkout,

```
Continuebtn.setText("Complete Checkout");
Continuebtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
{
 //System.out.println("Continuebtn.actionPerformed, event="+evt);
 //TODO add your code for Continuebtn.actionPerformed
 CashPay cashPay = new CashPay(TotalPrice);
 cashPay.setVisible(true);
}
});
```

Now, once the user selects all the items from the checkbox, you click on the Add Items button that will calculate the total amount, I found some errors in the method that was causing it not to calculate the total,

```
 public void checkwhatIsSelected() 
     {
         if(Strawberrychk.isSelected())
         {
             //is checked 
             TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
             System.out.println("   #################################################");
             System.out.println("       Your Total Price is: " + Pounds + TotalPrice);

             System.out.println("Thank you for shopping with Jstore, please come again!");
             System.out.println("   #################################################");
         }

         if(Appleschk.isSelected())
         {
             //is checked 
             TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 0.87;
             System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
         }   
       if(Orangeschk.isSelected())
         {
             //is checked 
             TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
             System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
         }
         if(Crispschk.isSelected())
         {
             //is checked 
             TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
             System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
         }
         if(Lambchk.isSelected())
         {
             //is checked 
             TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
             System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
         }
         if(Chickenchk.isSelected())
         {
             //is checked 
             TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
             System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
         }
         if(Juicechk.isSelected())
         {
             //is checked 
             TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
             System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
         }
         if(Smoothiechk.isSelected())
         {
             //is checked 
             TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
             System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
         }
         if(Sodachk.isSelected())
         {
             //is checked 
             TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
             System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
         }
         System.out.println("   #################################################");
         System.out.println("       Your Total Price is: " + Pounds + TotalPrice);

         System.out.println("Thank you for shopping with Jstore, please come again!");
         System.out.println("   #################################################");

     }
```

Now, one of the main changes is how your CashPay is instantiated from the ItemsPage class, first you do not need main for it, so I removed main and just passed the totalprice value into the constructor, plus look below to see where printTotalPrices() is called, it now in the Calculatebtn actionListener

```
double TotalPrice = 0;

    public CashPay(double TotalPrice) {
        super();
        this.TotalPrice = TotalPrice;
        initGUI();
    }
    public void printTotalPrice(){
        double CashInsert = Double.parseDouble(CashAmounttxt.getText());
    System.out.println(TotalPrice+" <> "+CashInsert);
        ChangeLeft = CashInsert - TotalPrice;
        System.out.println (ChangeLeft);
    }
    private void initGUI() 
  {
        try 
    {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            getContentPane().setLayout(null);

            cashamountlbl = new JLabel();
            getContentPane().add(cashamountlbl);
            cashamountlbl.setText("Enter Cash Amount");
            cashamountlbl.setBounds(41, 65, 105, 34);
            cashamountlbl.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(128,0,255));

            CashAmounttxt = new JTextField();
            getContentPane().add(CashAmounttxt);
            CashAmounttxt.setBounds(215, 71, 87, 23);

            CashChangelbl = new JLabel();
            getContentPane().add(CashChangelbl);
            CashChangelbl.setBounds(190, 117, 158, 109);
            CashChangelbl.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255,128,64));

            Calculatebtn = new JButton();
            getContentPane().add(Calculatebtn);
            Calculatebtn.setText("Calculate Total");
            Calculatebtn.setBounds(46, 203, 93, 23);
            Calculatebtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
                {
                  printTotalPrice();
                 } 
            });

            pack();
            this.setSize(415, 319);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //add your error handling code here
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is the complete solution that compiles and works,

```
/*
*
*/

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Checkbox;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


/**
* This code was edited or generated using CloudGarden's Jigloo
* SWT/Swing GUI Builder, which is free for non-commercial
* use. If Jigloo is being used commercially (ie, by a corporation,
* company or business for any purpose whatever) then you
* should purchase a license for each developer using Jigloo.
* Please visit www.cloudgarden.com for details.
* Use of Jigloo implies acceptance of these licensing terms.
* A COMMERCIAL LICENSE HAS NOT BEEN PURCHASED FOR
* THIS MACHINE, SO JIGLOO OR THIS CODE CANNOT BE USED
* LEGALLY FOR ANY CORPORATE OR COMMERCIAL PURPOSE.
*/
public class ItemsPage extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{
    private JLabel Fruitslbl;
    private JLabel Snackslbl;
    private JCheckBox Appleschk;
    private JCheckBox Strawberrychk;
    private JButton Continuebtn;
    private static JButton Additemsbtn;
    private JCheckBox Smoothiechk;
    private JCheckBox Juicechk;
    private JCheckBox Sodachk;
    private JCheckBox Lambchk;
    private JCheckBox Chickenchk;
    private JCheckBox Chocolatechk;
    private JCheckBox Crispschk;
    private JCheckBox Orangeschk;
    private JLabel Drinkslbl;
    private JLabel Meatlbl;
    public double TotalPrice;
    private String Pounds;



    /**
    * Auto-generated main method to display this JFrame
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ItemsPage inst = new ItemsPage();
                inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                inst.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public ItemsPage() 
  {
        Pounds = "£";
        initGUI();

    }

    private void initGUI() 
  {
        try 
    {
            GridBagLayout thisLayout = new GridBagLayout();
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            thisLayout.rowWeights = new double[] {0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1};
            thisLayout.rowHeights = new int[] {7, 7, 7, 7};
            thisLayout.columnWeights = new double[] {0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1};
            thisLayout.columnWidths = new int[] {7, 7, 7, 7};
            getContentPane().setLayout(thisLayout);
            this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("")).getImage());

            Fruitslbl = new JLabel();
            getContentPane().add(Fruitslbl, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            Fruitslbl.setText("Fruits");

            Snackslbl = new JLabel();
            getContentPane().add(Snackslbl, new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            Snackslbl.setText("Snacks");

            Meatlbl = new JLabel();
            getContentPane().add(Meatlbl, new GridBagConstraints(2, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            Meatlbl.setText("Meat");

            Drinkslbl = new JLabel();
            getContentPane().add(Drinkslbl, new GridBagConstraints(3, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            Drinkslbl.setText("Drinks");

            Appleschk = new JCheckBox();
            getContentPane().add(Appleschk, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            Appleschk.setText("Apples");

            Orangeschk = new JCheckBox();
            getContentPane().add(Orangeschk, new GridBagConstraints(0, 2, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            Orangeschk.setText("Oranges");

            Strawberrychk = new JCheckBox();
            getContentPane().add(Strawberrychk, new GridBagConstraints(0, 3, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            Strawberrychk.setText("Strawberry");


            Crispschk = new JCheckBox();
            getContentPane().add(Crispschk, new GridBagConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            Crispschk.setText("Crisps");



            Chocolatechk = new JCheckBox();
            getContentPane().add(Chocolatechk, new GridBagConstraints(1, 2, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            Chocolatechk.setText("Chocolate");

            Chickenchk = new JCheckBox();
            getContentPane().add(Chickenchk, new GridBagConstraints(2, 1, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            Chickenchk.setText("Chicken");

            Lambchk = new JCheckBox();
            getContentPane().add(Lambchk, new GridBagConstraints(2, 2, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            Lambchk.setText("Lamb");

            Sodachk = new JCheckBox();
            getContentPane().add(Sodachk, new GridBagConstraints(3, 1, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            Sodachk.setText("Soda");

            Juicechk = new JCheckBox();
            getContentPane().add(Juicechk, new GridBagConstraints(3, 2, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            Juicechk.setText("Juice");

            Smoothiechk = new JCheckBox();
            getContentPane().add(Smoothiechk, new GridBagConstraints(3, 3, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            Smoothiechk.setText("Smoothie");

            Additemsbtn = new JButton();
            getContentPane().add(Additemsbtn, new GridBagConstraints(1, 3, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            Additemsbtn.setText("Add Items");
            Additemsbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    //System.out.println("Additemsbtn.actionPerformed, event="+evt+TotalPrice);
                    //TODO add your code for Additemsbtn.actionPerformed
                    checkwhatIsSelected();
                }
            });

            Continuebtn = new JButton();
            getContentPane().add(Continuebtn, new GridBagConstraints(2, 3, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            Continuebtn.setText("Complete Checkout");
            Continuebtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
        {
                    //System.out.println("Continuebtn.actionPerformed, event="+evt);
                    //TODO add your code for Continuebtn.actionPerformed
                    CashPay cashPay = new CashPay(TotalPrice);
          cashPay.setVisible(true);
                }
            });

            pack();
            this.setSize(841, 593);
        } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
            //add your error handling code here
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    // private void handleJCheckbox(double Strawberrychk) {



        // if (Strawberrychk. == true)
        //   TotalPrice += 1.99;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return false;}

     public void checkwhatIsSelected() 
     {
         if(Strawberrychk.isSelected())
         {
             //is checked 
             TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
             System.out.println("   #################################################");
             System.out.println("       Your Total Price is: " + Pounds + TotalPrice);

             System.out.println("Thank you for shopping with Jstore, please come again!");
             System.out.println("   #################################################");
         }

         if(Appleschk.isSelected())
         {
             //is checked 
             TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 0.87;
             System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
         }   
       if(Orangeschk.isSelected())
         {
                 //is checked 
             TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
             System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
     }
         if(Crispschk.isSelected())
         {
             //is checked 
             TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
             System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
         }
         if(Lambchk.isSelected())
         {
             //is checked 
             TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
             System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
         }
         if(Chickenchk.isSelected())
         {
             //is checked 
             TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
             System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
         }
         if(Juicechk.isSelected())
         {
             //is checked 
             TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
             System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
         }
         if(Smoothiechk.isSelected())
         {
             //is checked 
             TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
             System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
         }
         if(Sodachk.isSelected())
         {
             //is checked 
             TotalPrice = TotalPrice + 1.99;
             System.out.println("Your Total Price is " + Pounds + TotalPrice);
         }
         System.out.println("   #################################################");
         System.out.println("       Your Total Price is: " + Pounds + TotalPrice);

         System.out.println("Thank you for shopping with Jstore, please come again!");
         System.out.println("   #################################################");

     }
}



import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


/**
* This code was edited or generated using CloudGarden's Jigloo
* SWT/Swing GUI Builder, which is free for non-commercial
* use. If Jigloo is being used commercially (ie, by a corporation,
* company or business for any purpose whatever) then you
* should purchase a license for each developer using Jigloo.
* Please visit www.cloudgarden.com for details.
* Use of Jigloo implies acceptance of these licensing terms.
* A COMMERCIAL LICENSE HAS NOT BEEN PURCHASED FOR
* THIS MACHINE, SO JIGLOO OR THIS CODE CANNOT BE USED
* LEGALLY FOR ANY CORPORATE OR COMMERCIAL PURPOSE.
*/
public class CashPay extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private JLabel cashamountlbl;
    private JButton Calculatebtn;
    private JLabel CashChangelbl;
    private JTextField CashAmounttxt;
    private double ChangeLeft;

    double TotalPrice = 0;

    public CashPay(double TotalPrice) {
        super();
        this.TotalPrice = TotalPrice;
        initGUI();
    }
    public void printTotalPrice(){
        double CashInsert = Double.parseDouble(CashAmounttxt.getText());
    System.out.println(TotalPrice+" <> "+CashInsert);
        ChangeLeft = CashInsert - TotalPrice;
        System.out.println (ChangeLeft);
    }
    private void initGUI() 
  {
        try 
    {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            getContentPane().setLayout(null);

            cashamountlbl = new JLabel();
            getContentPane().add(cashamountlbl);
            cashamountlbl.setText("Enter Cash Amount");
            cashamountlbl.setBounds(41, 65, 105, 34);
            cashamountlbl.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(128,0,255));

            CashAmounttxt = new JTextField();
            getContentPane().add(CashAmounttxt);
            CashAmounttxt.setBounds(215, 71, 87, 23);

            CashChangelbl = new JLabel();
            getContentPane().add(CashChangelbl);
            CashChangelbl.setBounds(190, 117, 158, 109);
            CashChangelbl.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255,128,64));

            Calculatebtn = new JButton();
            getContentPane().add(Calculatebtn);
            Calculatebtn.setText("Calculate Total");
            Calculatebtn.setBounds(46, 203, 93, 23);
            Calculatebtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
      {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
        {
                  printTotalPrice();
        } 
            });

            pack();
            this.setSize(415, 319);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //add your error handling code here
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all I would like to thank you so much for taking your time to reply to me and being so patient. I did everything you asked me commented out the cashpay main method but the left the main for ItemsPage I received this error message. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at ItemsPage.main(ItemsPage.java:54)

Comment: let me append the complete solution that compiled and worked for me at the end of my answer

Comment: Perfect Thank you, an issue I had was the Action Listener I was getting a red line under it, eclipse suggested to load ActionListener and event into library I did that it works now I really appreciate your help, problem with me is that I did my stuff in GUI and I've been looking at youtube tutorials and that's why I had wrong stuff. I can't thank you enough I like the way you posted comments explaining each section you modified.

Comment: Hi again, sorry to bother you. I modified my code so rather than clicking continuebtn to take me to cashpay jframe so it takes me to "paymentmethod" class/jframe  so the user can choose whether they want to pay by card or by cash, how would I pass my variable that way? would I pass the variable to paymentmethod then pass it from there to cashpay? or is there an easier method to directly pass it to cashpay?, I tried that "cashpay cashpay = new cashpay(); but it's giving me issues without the setvisible because we just want the variable to be passed not open the actual cashpay.

Comment: Got it to work, just had to pass the variable 3x, from itemspage to payment method to cashpay.

Comment: btw I tried to give you +1 but not high enough rep :( sorry